# Get all applications that can open a specific file (using the command line)

Tags: files

I want to write my own "open with" GUI for Ubuntu. In Ubuntu, is it possible to get a list of applications that can open a specified file (from the command line?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mimeopen` command to list the applications which is capable of opening the file.

Example: Say If I have to open a tar file. I can use the command

```
mimeopen -d test.tar
```

The sample output will be something like this

```
$mimeopen -d test.tar 
Please choose a default application for files of type application/x-tar

    1) Archive Manager  (file-roller)
    2) Archive Mounter  (mount-archive)
    3) Other...

use application #
```

When you choose the 3rd option, you will be asked to enter a command which is capable of opening a tar file.

Comment: Is it possible to do this for applications in the Ubuntu Software Center (as well as already-installed applications?) http://askubuntu.com/questions/223924/get-downloadable-applications-that-can-open-a-specific-file-type

Comment: Need to investigate. Will get back to you.