# Get downloadable applications that can open a specific file type

Tags: software-center

I'm trying to create a custom "open with" dialog that allows the user to open a file with a not-yet-installed application. In Ubuntu, is it possible to obtain a list of programs that can be used to open a file? I need to find a list of downloadable programs (instead of installed programs) that can open a file, from the command line.

Comment: I know this doesn't help, but I really doubt that it is possible as it would require a huge DB of MIME-types. I might be wrong though.

Comment: @MiJyn Why wouldn't it be feasible to query a large database of MIME-types?

Answer (score 3):

[PackageKit](http://www.packagekit.org/) allows you to search for applications by mime-type. Sadly, the Ubuntu devs haven't put much effort into integrating PackageKit with Ubuntu by default, but it still works surprisingly well.

First, make sure you've installed the graphical toolkit for PackageKit, [gnome-packagekit-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-packagekit-tools) [image: Install gnome-packagekit-tools].

Then, run `gpk-install-mime-type` on the command line, followed by a mime-type. For example:

```
gpk-install-mime-type text/plain
```

Screenshots:

[image: First gpk-install-mime-type confirmation dialog]

[image: Dialog listing applicable packages]

Comment: It looks like you posted the same answer to two separate questions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/224001/list-programs-in-the-ubuntu-software-center-by-file-association/224022#224022

Comment: I know. I realise they're different questions, but this answer is useful for both of them. I'm not sure what the policy is on copying and pasting like this.

Comment: Here is a relevant discussion relating to this issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36648/copying-the-answers-for-a-duplicate-question

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you would need to compile the information yourself.  You would need to compile the file types and associations with programs in the package manager.  A lengthy task, but I'd be happy to help.  Sounds like a worth while project.  We could even open source the task and get others to help.  You can go to my site and send me an email from the contact form.

Other then that known file types are stored internally in most linux distros to a smaller degree.  Here is a question that addresses that [Where are file associations stored?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16580/where-are-file-associations-stored)

Comment: Which package manager are you referring to specifically?

Comment: apt-get is the package manager I use and theoretically you could probably set it up to work with other package managers and distros, but it might be more work.

Comment: Here's a relevant question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/224001/get-file-associations-for-applications-that-havent-yet-been-installed

Comment: There's a program called PackageKit that you can use to obtain a list of programs for a specific mime type: http://askubuntu.com/a/224022/71277