# List programs in the Ubuntu Software Center by file association

Tags: package-management

In Ubuntu, is there any way to obtain a list of file associations for applications that haven't yet been installed? I'd like to find the files that a not-yet-installed software application (e.g. google-chrome or firefox) can open.

I currently don't know of any feature in the Ubuntu Software Center (or another application) that can list the filetypes associated with a specific application - does such a feature exist?

Comment: The file associations for installed applications can be found in `usr/share/applications`, but I don't yet know how to find the file associations for applications that aren't yet installed.

Comment: You can just modify your original question at http://askubuntu.com/questions/223924/get-downloadable-applications-that-can-open-a-specific-file-type

Comment: @Goddard These are really two separate questions - this one is asking whether it's possible to obtain a list of file types for a specific application, while the other is asking how to obtain a list of applications for a specific file type.

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/xdg-mime.1.html might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PackageKit](http://www.packagekit.org/) allows you to search for applications by mime-type. Sadly, the Ubuntu devs haven't put much effort into integrating PackageKit with Ubuntu by default, but it still works surprisingly well.

First, make sure you've installed the graphical toolkit for PackageKit, [gnome-packagekit-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-packagekit-tools) [image: Install gnome-packagekit-tools].

Then, run `gpk-install-mime-type` on the command line, followed by a mime-type. For example:

```
gpk-install-mime-type text/plain
```

Screenshots:

[image: First gpk-install-mime-type confirmation dialog]

[image: Dialog listing applicable packages]

Comment: Is there a command-line interface for packagekit? I want to find out how to obtain a list of applications associated with a specific mime type.

Comment: There is a program called pkcon for this specific purpose: http://www.packagekit.org/pk-using.html

Comment: If you can figure out how to use it for this purpose, please edit my answer or add your own.